# Branch error Warning. Session initialization already happened. (-118)

Tags: android, branch.io, android-deep-link

I have a launcher Activity, which is set to receive deep Branch intents.

When there arent any Activities in the back stack, `onInitFinished(JSONObject, BranchError)` gives this BranchError, and jSONProject is null:

> Warning. Session initialization already happened. To force a new session, set intent extra, "branch_force_new_session", to true.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="LauncherActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="my.domain.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Activity:

```
class LauncherActivity : Branch.BranchReferralInitListener {

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        Branch.sessionBuilder(this).withCallback(this).withData(parseIntent().data).init()

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            IntegrationValidator.validate(this)
        }
    }

    private fun parseIntent(): Intent {
        var newIntent = Intent()
        newIntent = newIntent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session", true)
        newIntent = newIntent.putExtra("branch", intent.dataString)
        return newIntent
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        this.intent = intent

        Branch.sessionBuilder(this).withCallback(this).withData(parseIntent().data).reInit()
    }

    override fun onInitFinished(referringParams: JSONObject?, error: BranchError?) {
        if (error != null) {
            // Getting error only when app is not backgrounded
        } else if (referringParams != null) {
            // When app is backgrounded, it works
        }
    }
}
```

When an intent is received and the app is backgrounded, everything works.  When the app is launched due to a branch intent, I'm getting an error and the referringParams are null.  I've tried delaying the initialization as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can see that you are initializing the SDK in your DeepLinkActivity. Though in the Manifest you have LauncherActivity. Can you confirm on which Activity is launched through the deep link and then initialize the SDK in that activity?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I changed the Activity name when posting, but didnt update the Activity class. Initialization is definitely being done in the Launcher activity

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be already addressed by the Branch team.
There is no fix as of now, but you can try a workaround they recommended [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking-attribution/issues/808#issuecomment-608285296).

```
if else (error.getErrorCode() === BranchError.ERR_BRANCH_ALREADY_INITIALIZED) {
   branchReferringPramas_ = Branch.getLatestReferringParams(); 
}
```

Comment: It should be  branchReferringPramas_ = Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams()